# CoronaSDK- How to handle touch and tap at the same time

Tags: coronasdk

I have a case I couldn't find a solution for. In my game, moving your finger moves the objects around. But there is another scenario. If you are in a certain "mode", tapping certain object should do something specific, but if the user doesn't click on that specific object, I need to reset the mode to normal.

I have a system event touch handler that handles the move. I also have an event handler on the objects which are mode aware. Now the problem is resetting mode back to normal. 
System touch event handler is called before object tap event, so I cannot handle it there as I am not sure if the tap event is going to fire or not. And if the tap didn't happen on the specific object, I have no way of handling it.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've handled a similar situation by just setting a Boolean to true when you enter the certain "mode" and setting it to false on every tap/touch end. - Throw a conditional in there to check if the current object is a recipient of the "mode", if not, set the dragging bool to false..

-Really nothing fancy needed from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

An object can have both a touch and a tap handler on it.  A tap is a well defined short duration touch and release though and it may not do what you want, because if you touch, hold too long and then release, it won't register as a tap event.

Your best bet is to just code your touch handler to see if you got any move phases and if you get an end after a begin without any move's, then act as if you were tapped.

Comment: I want to know what is tapped. But I have tap handler only on the objects that can react. Some objects should not react. My idea was that in case they are tapped, just revert to normal move mode. But I cannot find a way to do so